# Preventing UITableView reload multiple times in xib

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a xib which has a tableview. I instantiate the view controller using :

```
[[ViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewController" bundle:bundle]
```

I see that the tableview is loaded once before the viewWillAppear. Is there a way to prevent this? I want the tableview reload to happen *after* viewWillAppear.

Comment: You can e.g register your ViewController as delegate and datasource for UITableView in viewWillAppear method. (I assume that now you have that in viewDidLoad)

Comment: instantiate and add the viewController as a subview in the viewDidAppear, if that's what you want to do